# not working - assign a value to a variable that has not been declared it will automatically become a global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have been told that in JavaScript,if you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared it will automatically become a global variable, even if it present inside a function.

I have the code:

```
function helloWorld2(){
            greeting2 = "hello world 2";
}
document.write(greeting2);
```

But netbeans output the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: greeting2 is not defined (15:58:36:083 | error, javascript)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: But have you called `helloWorld2` function ? Try `helloWorld2()` before `document.write`

Comment: @Rayon Thank you so much! It worked! So I guess I have to use the function first before the variable comes global.

Comment: Variable will become global only if function holding that variable is `invoked`

Comment: @Rayon do you mind if I ask, why does javascript allow global variable declaration like this? Cause from my/javascript beginner's point of view, this can cause a lot of confusions.

Comment: Some [__Food__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it) for you...

Comment: @dzjustinli2: Because it was thought to be clever initially. It's disallowed in strict mode (and throws an exception) exactly because it causes too much confusion and lets slips go through unnoticed.